# Script to identify who is restoring database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, database-administration

Is there a script to identify the user who is restoring the database in SQL Server?

Comment: Check this out http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1724/when-was-the-last-time-your-sql-server-database-was-restored/

Answer (score 3):

Once the restore is done, check who the database owner is. While it's running, you can look at the current sessions.

Answer (score 2):

You can write a query as:

```
SELECT destination_database_name,
       restore_date,
       user_name
FROM msdb.dbo.[restorehistory] 
WHERE restore_date>GETDATE()
AND destination_database_name = 'DB Name'
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, i searched for msdb.dbo.[backuphistory], but it is not there. +1 to your query.

Comment: @knkarthick24: backup history is kept in multiple tables in msdb. All of which start with backup. Do `select name from msdb.sys.tables where name like 'backup%'` to find them all and then consult the docs to see what they're for.